# SQL: "Column 'tbl.column' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js

I was wondering why i'm getting the following error:
`Column 'tbl.column' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`
when the sql statement looks like:
`SELECT tbl.column, MAX(tblOther.columnOtherId) AS otherID FROM (tbl INNER JOIN tblOther ON tbl.columnId = tblOther.columnOtherId) INNER JOIN tblOtherAgain ON tblOther.columnOtherId = tblOtherAgain.columnAgainOtherId WHERE tblOther.columnOtherAgainId = @id`.

When I remove the aggregate function **MAX** on `tblOther.columnOtherId` I don't receive the above error. So how do I get the statement shown above to work without getting the shown error?

DBLibrary: ***Tedious.js***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have use an aggregate function `MAX()` and there is a field in the `SELECT` clause which is not aggregated that is why you need to have `GROUP BY` clause,

```
SELECT  tbl.column, 
        MAX(tblOther.columnOtherId) AS otherID 
FROM    (tbl INNER JOIN tblOther 
            ON tbl.columnId = tblOther.columnOtherId) 
        INNER JOIN tblOtherAgain 
            ON tblOther.columnOtherId = tblOtherAgain.SourceId 
WHERE   tblOther.columnOtherAgainId = @id
GROUP   BY tbl.column
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbl.column, MAX(tblOther.columnOtherId) AS otherID FROM (tbl INNER JOIN tblOther ON tbl.columnId = tblOther.columnOtherId) INNER JOIN tblOtherAgain ON tblOther.columnOtherId = tblOtherAgain.columnAgainOtherId WHERE tblOther.columnOtherAgainId = @id
GROUP BY tbl.column
```

Comment: Since @JW got the answer in first it is going to be his that is selected as correct even though yours is too.