# Column 'Course.Course_Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, count, group-by, inner-join

I need to link two tables columns, please help me. This my code:

```
SELECT Student.Stu_Course_ID, Course.Course_Name, COUNT(Student.Stu_ID) AS NoOfStudent FROM Student
INNER JOIN Course
ON Student.Stu_Course_ID=Course.Course_ID
GROUP BY Stu_Course_ID;
```

This is my course table:

```
 __________________________________________
|Course_ID | Course_Name                   |
|1         | B.Eng in Software Engineering | 
|2         | M.Eng in Software Engineering |
|3         | BSC in Business IT            |
```

I got number of students from student table

```
 _____________________________
|Stu_Course_ID | NoOfStudents |
|1             | 30           | 
|2             | 12           |
|3             | 20           |
```

This is what i want

```
 ____________________________________________________________
|Stu_Course_ID | Course_Name                   | NoOfStudents| 
|1             | B.Eng in Software Engineering | 30          |
|2             | M.Eng in Software Engineering | 12          |
|3             | BSC in Business IT            | 20          |
```

Comment: Help you do what? Your join is fine, and the error code seems fairly self explanatory. If you have 10 students on a course, I assume you want a count of 10 for the course_name, however which batch id should show in your first column? You either need to omit this from the select list, or include it in an aggregate function, or include it in the group by clause.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: "Column 'tbl.column' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027818/sql-column-tbl-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contai)

Comment: i dont get it, can you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `Course.Course_Name` to your group by clause:

```
SELECT Student.Stu_Course_ID, 
        Course.Course_Name, 
        COUNT(Student.Stu_ID) AS NoOfStudent
FROM Student
INNER JOIN Course
ON Student.Stu_Course_ID=Course.Course_ID
GROUP BY Student.Stu_Course_ID, Course.Course_Name;
```

Imagine the following simple table (T):

```
ID  | Column1 | Column2  |
----|---------+----------|
1   |    A    |    X     |
2   |    A    |    Y     |
```

Your query is similary to this:

```
SELECT  ID, Column1, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM    T
GROUP BY Column1;
```

So, you know you have 2 records for `A` in column1, so you expect a count of 2, however, you are also selecting `ID`, there are two different values for `ID` where Column1 = A, so the following result:

```
ID  | Column1 |  Count   |
----|---------+----------|
1   |    A    |    2     |
```

Is no more or less correct than

```
ID  | Column1 |  Count   |
----|---------+----------|
2   |    A    |    2     |
```

This is why `ID` cannot be contained in the select list, unless it included in the group by clause, or as part of an aggregate function.

For what it's worth, if `Course_ID` is the primary key in the table `Course` then following query is legal according to the SQL Standard, and will work in Postgresql, and I suspect at some point Microsoft will build this functionality into SQL Server too:

```
SELECT Course.Course_ID, 
        Course.Course_Name, 
        COUNT(Student.Stu_ID) AS NoOfStudent
FROM Student
INNER JOIN Course
ON Student.Stu_Course_ID=Course.Course_ID
GROUP BY Course.Course_ID;
```

The reason for this is that since `Course.Course_ID` is the primary key of `Course` there can be no duplicates of this in the table, therefore there can only be one value for `Course_name` for each `Course_ID`

Answer (score 0):

give columns names after group by statements which you want to retreive so you have to also give Course.Course_Name as well...

Comment: i dont get it, can you help me!